# Joomla custom menu with php and mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla

I'm working on a project based on Joomla.

We are not using the joomla register/login default form, instead we have created a custom registration/login system based on our mysql tables.

We need to dynamically modify the joomla main menu:

we have to change the menu items if an user is logged in (we see if an user is logged by checking some values in the session and testing tokens), so we need to make a mysql query and then alter the menu items dynamically.
How can we should do this ? Is even possible to insert custom php code in the joomla main menu ?

Comment: I would look into developing my own menu module instead of using the core menu from Joomla, that way you can build it the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by editing the file /modules/mod_menu/helper.php

Comment: If this file gets updated in a Joomla update, your changes will be overridden. Hope you know this

Comment: Yep I was aware, so I made a couple of backups of this file. Thank you for pointing this out ;)